# How to change .mdb database password by C# code?

Tags: database, windows, c#-4.0

I want to change my .mdb Database password by C# code. I am using following code for this but some error comes. So please help me.

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005). This error comes.

Code:

```
  OleDbConnection cnn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + pwd + ";Mode=Share Exclusive");
  OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
  cnn1.Open();
  cmd1.Connection = cnn1;


  string Query="ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD <newPassword> " + pwd + "";  

  cmd1.CommandText = Query;
  blnSuccess = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Last finally i got the answer of my Question.

Following code is help me for change the .mdb Database Password change by C# Code.

> Add a reference to Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

```
using DAO;

public void ChangePassword(string sDBPath, string sDBPasswordOld, string sDBPasswordNew)
{
     dao.DBEngine dbEngine;
     dao.Database db;
     db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(sDBPath, true, false, ";PWD=" + sDBPasswordOld);
     db.NewPassword(sDBPasswordOld, sDBPasswordNew);
}
```